# Smartsheets Formula - Exclude Rollup / Summary Tasks from Summary Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm (newly) using Smartsheets to build & track Project Plans

My Smartsheet has Rollup / Summary Tasks, Deliverables / Tasks and Milestones. On the Summary Sheet, I only want to count the actual Deliverables/Tasks i.e. not the Rollup / Summary tasks or milestones.

I found how to add a column that determines whether a row is a child or a parent using -

=IF(COUNT(CHILDREN([Task Name]@row)) = 0, 1)

And I've managed to add a formula in my Summary sheet that reads -

=COUNTIFS(Workstream:Workstream, "Supplier Engagement", Status:Status, "Yet to Start", Child:Child, 1, Duration:Duration, "<>0")

However, I dont really want the Child column in my sheet and would prefer to have the formula in the Summary sheet (so replacing 'Child:Child, 1')

Something like

=COUNTIFS(Workstream:Workstream, "Supplier Engagement", Status:Status, "Yet to Start", **(COUNT(CHILDREN([Task Name]@row)) = 0, 1)**, 1, Duration:Duration, "<>0")

Any guidance on how to combine these?

Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest you post this question to the [Formulas and Functions](https://community.smartsheet.com/categories/formulas-and-functions) area of the Smartsheet Community forum instead of posting here on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is the place to ask programming/coding related questions (i.e., if you're using the Smartsheet API to programmatically access Smartsheet data), whereas the Community Forum is the place to ask questions about in-app functionality (like your question about formulas). Good luck!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responses, One of the SmartSheets experts has answered this query - Thank you

Comment: Don't post comments as an answer.